# Appfabric local cache notifications

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I want to see if my understanding of Appfabric local cache invalidation is correct

Assume I have notification based invalidation set up on my local cache
The default polling interval is 5 minutes

Which way does the polling occur? I believe the local cache polls the distributed cache to check for notifications, is this correct?

Does that mean that if a change occurs to the distributed cache it could be anywhere up to 5 minutes before that item in the local cache is invalidated depending on when the last sync occurred?

Is there any way to see the last synched time, through powershell or another mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, local polls server each pollInterval. The interval can be [customized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790880.aspx).
2. Yes, that's correct
3. Doubt about powershell. Maybe there will be some trace events in case you use [Set-CacheLogging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177%28v=azure.10%29.aspx#cachehost) but I didn't try. What will definitely work is to subscribe to [cache notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808091.aspx) right in the code and put a breakpoint into it.